# Reason behind that object addresses must differ if types are the same, but addresses can be the same if types differ

Tags: c++

We have empty base class optimization. Look at these two cases:

**Case A**

```
struct Empty1 { };
struct Empty2 { };
struct One: Empty1, Empty2 { };
```

Here, `sizeof(One)` is 1. Addresses of `Empty1` and `Empty2` are the same.

**Case B**

```
struct Empty { };
struct Empty1: public Empty { };
struct Empty2: public Empty { };
struct Two: Empty1, Empty2 { };
```

Here, `sizeof(Two)` is 2. Addresses of `Empty1` and `Empty2` differ, because both of them have `Empty` (and these `Empty`s should have differing addresses).

Why does the standard allow to have the same address for differing types, but disallow for same types? What problem does this rule avoid?

What problem will I have, if I create a `tuple` implementation where all empty members will have the same address (no matter of their types)?

Comment: In your sample you are talking about base classes. In your question about members of tuple. Two things seems to be unrelated

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky: there are two questions, and these are highly related in my opinion (both of them are about having the same address of objects). And `tuples` are usually implemented with inheritance, where EBO is used.

Comment: I would say that the rule is inherited from C. You might have array of `Empty`. so sizeof cannot be `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The address is part of the identity of an object. Separate objects of the same type having separate addresses is a general rule. That's how you know that there is more than one object.

In copy constructors you can often find a test for self-assignment `if (this != &other)`. This would fail if different objects of the same type were to have the same address.

Objects of different types cannot be compared like this anyway, so not a problem. And we also have a struct and its first member and an array and the first element that *have* the same address, but are of different types.

The empty base class poses a problem here, but only if you have two base classes of the same type, or the base class happens to be of the same type as the first member of the derived class. So there are special rules to forbid the overlap of two identical objects in those cases.

The idea is that they should be two separate sub-objects and work in a `this != &that` test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For empty classes, assignment is an empty function (because it has nothing to copy), isn't it? So you wouldn't write identity test in it.

Comment: But which issue can happen ? As the class is empty, there are no non-static member, the test with self seems unneeded.

Comment: @Jarod42 - That's an example of where you need to know if you have one or two objects, and use their addresses for that. Separate objects of the same type having separate addresses is a general rule. For example, why would you want to have a base class and a first member of the derived class if you cannot tell them apart?

Comment: @BoPersson: "Separate objects of the same type having separate addresses is a general rule". Basically, that's my question: why is it? Are there any drawbacks if this rule wouldn't exist? "why would you want to have a base class and a first member of the derived class if you cannot tell them apart?" I don't understand what you mean here. Can you please explain?

Comment: @geza - Suppose you have `class Derived : Empty { Empty  member; };` and a pointer `Empty*  ptr`. Wouldn't it be confusing if a pointer to the base class and a pointer to the member were identical? At least the committee believed that and require them to be different. Even if `Empty` stores no data it can have member functions that behave differently for different values of `this` (not limited to copy constructors :-).

Comment: Okay, now I see what you mean. I don't really consider this case as important though. I cannot imagine any code for which this distinction is useful. Maybe the committee should have allowed zero-sized objects (as I currently see, it has more benefits than drawbacks).

Answer (score 1):

The rule is stated in the standard [intro.object]:

> Unless an object is a bit-field or a base class subobject of zero size, the address of that object is the address
>   of the first byte it occupies. Two objects a and b with overlapping lifetimes that are not bit-fields may have
>   the same address if one is nested within the other, or if at least one is a base class subobject of zero size and
>   they are of different types; otherwise, they have distinct addresses.

One reason why an *empty base class* fall on this rule is because
one can cast an *empty base class* reference, to a reference of the base object.

The best is to see it in action, I have added the assembly generated by gcc with -O3 optimization:

```
struct Empty1 { };
struct Empty2 { };
struct One: Empty1, Empty2 { 
  int i;
};
struct Other{
  int i;
};

//an Empty and a One may have the same address                                              
int f(Empty1& a,One& b){   mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], 12  //write to *rsi
  b.i=12;                  mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], 15  //may be rsi==rdi
  auto& a_one =            mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsi] //reload from *rsi
    static_cast<One&>(a);  ret
  a_one.i=15;                         
  return b.i;                        
}    

//an int and a One may have the same address                                              
int f(int& a,One& b){      mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], 12  //write to *rsi                           
  b.i=12;                  mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], 15  //may be rsi==rdi                         
  a=15;                    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsi] //reload from *rsi
  return b.i;              ret                                                   
}        

//a long can not have the same address as a One 
int f(long& a,One& b){     mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], 12                        
  b.i=12;                  mov     eax, 12  //aliasing optimization
  a=15;                    mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], 15 //sure rsi!=rdi aliasing rule
  return b.i;              ret                        
}   

//the int inside and Other can alias an int inside a One
int f(Other& a,One& b){     mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], 12                        
  b.i=12;                  mov     eax, 12  //aliasing optimization
  a.i=15;                    mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], 15 //sure rsi!=rdi aliasing rule
  return b.i;              ret                        
}
```

Only one complete object can exist at a given address. The complete object is the one that is not nested within another.

It is impossible to succeed to have to object at the same address (without UB), with the same type. But since you object are empty, you do not need more than one in your optimized tuple. You will only need to implement a `get<I>` which referes to the same object for all `Is` that are meant to refer to object of of the same empty class.

Comment: "One reason why an empty base class fall on this rule is because one can cast an empty base class  reference, to a reference of the base object." I don't understand what you mean here. "If two empty object different object with the same type and same address could exist, it would be impossible to perform some allowed static_cast." Can you give an example of this?

Comment: This sentence is indeed not jutified in your case. So the good reason is probably that if the standard had to take care of all this very special cases, the c++ rules, would be even more difficult to grasp, while the benefits since realy questionable. For your special case the work around is trivial.